# Where is the grub on this dual boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I just made a dual boot on my PC.
I had the windows previously installed on a 512G ssd and installed ubuntu on a 2T HD.
After a little of reseach (I'm a very begginer) I did the normal installation of ubuntu, selecting to erase disk and selected the 2TB HD. All worked fine but I have a small doubt about where boot loader went/where needed to go.

Here I have the Screenshots showing my doubt.
The ubuntu installer managed to create a EFI partition of 512 MB super well on the HD, this of what I have read is the probable location of the boot loader, since I'm on UEFI mode.
But, after searching on the windowds EFI partition (on the SSD), the ubunbtu folder was there.
Was not the ideal to put the boot loader on the previously created EFI partition on the HD? If not, why was this EFI partition created?

Thanks and regards!

The EFI partiton
[image: the EFI partiton]

The ubuntu folder on the SSD
[image: The ubuntu folder on the SSD]

Comment: The same thing happened to me way back on 14.04 The installer seems to use the first EFI partition it finds. I, too, had made a separate one, but it used the Windows one.

Comment: Microsoft has requried vendors to install Windows in UEFI with gpt partitioning since 2012. But it looks like your Windows is an old BIOS with MBR partitioning? Upgrade from Windows 7 or incorrect install? And then Ubuntu is installed in UEFI boot mode. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #55 or( #23 & #26)
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Others suggest disconnecting all other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive.